# Returning DraftJS html to parent component

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm trying to render the input of my draft editor into a parent component.

So far, I've used the module [draft-js-utils](https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils) to generate HTML from my draftJS editor and am able to bring this value to my parent component.

My issues is that when I display that value in the parent component, it won't render as HTML, but as an HTML string. Should I be sending something else to my parent?

```
const Parent = () => {

  const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState('')

  const _returnHTMLPicker = (v) => {
    return(v)
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Child _returnHTMLPicker={_returnHTMLPicker}/>
      {returnHTML}
    </div>
  )
}

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = editorState => {
      this.setState({editorState});
      this.props._currentReturnedHTML(stateToHTML(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()));
    }
  }

  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`stateToHTML` returns a string containing HTML. If you want to display the HTML in the browser, the component diplaying it needs to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which will convert it to DOM objects that the browser will display the way you would expect.

Comment: Hello @mzedeler, Thank you for your response. This is how I have it set up today. I'm not sure using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is the optimal approach though. 

My question is if I can use the state directly to renderin my JSX without relying on an external library like `stateToHTML`

Comment: Only if you write your own conversion code that converts to HTML. Try using my approach to see that it actually works. After that, you can extend our modify it.

Comment: Hi Mzedeler, your method works. It's how it's set up in my project at the moment. I just feel there is most likely a way to do it without relying on an external library. (`stateToHTML`). I would much rather use a method already existing within draftJS.

Comment: It depends on what problem you're trying to solve. If it is just a question of displaying the same thing as what is in the editor, just read only, you can set up a second editor, pass the `editorState` to it, and set the `readOnly` flag. That is by far the easiest solution, but it may not be what you need.